# Finding and Tagging Duplicates in R

Tags: r

I was looking for an optimize way to do a task using R
Task: Find a way to assign 1 and 0 corresponds to a column entries, if entries are repeated then assign 1 for the first time occurrence of the value and rest time assign 0.

```
Example
ID      assigned value
2012            1
2012            0
2012            0
2014            1
2016            1
2015            1
```

Here id is a vector contain id and assign vector will hold values accordingly.
My Solution:

```
   for(num in 1:(nrow(Final_file)-1))
   { 
     if((Final_file[num,'ID']) == (Final_file[(num+1),'ID']))
     {
       assign_value[num] <- c('0')
            }
     else
     { assign_value[num] <- c('1')
     }  
    }
```

Here Final_file is sorted according to ID, my Solution is working but it take around 40 min to perform this logic on a file which contains 21K Rows. I want a code that will take less time to do the same task.

Answer (score 0):

See `?duplicated`

```
#set up data (you should have done this part for us)
ID <- c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2014L, 2016L, 2015L)

# one way of getting what you want:
1-duplicated(ID)
```

I just did this on my cheap little laptop. It did a vector of 2.1 million IDs in well under a second (though the IDs were all in a vector in memory)

```
data.frame(ID=ID,assigned.value=1-duplicated(ID))
    ID assigned.value
1 2012              1
2 2012              0
3 2012              0
4 2014              1
5 2016              1
6 2015              1
```

Comment: mine program run a file with 7 column and 21K rows and this operation is done on last column and a new vector will get values accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're saying there.